# Right way to play audio in browser?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I've created simple audio player in browser but have some troubles.
For example I have 20 audio tags in my html code.

```
            <audio class="tr_audio">
               <source src="track1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
               <source src="ogg/track1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            </audio>
         <audio class="tr_audio">
               <source src="track2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
               <source src="ogg/track2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            </audio>
         <audio class="tr_audio">
               <source src="track3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
               <source src="ogg/track3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            </audio>
           ...
         <audio class="tr_audio">
               <source src="track20.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
               <source src="ogg/track20.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            </audio>
```

and have list with 20 items. One item for one track. And I play it on click event. Trouble that when page is loading all 20 tracks loading in cache, right? And some tracks may can not be loaded at all or loaded partially. So, attempt to play such track will be fail. (for example track17 wasn't loaded and if I click on item17 song will not play). Also, I stop the previous song like this

```
$('.'+part+'_audio')[song_number].currentTime = 0;
    $('.' part '_audio')[song_number].pause();
```

So, if the previous track wasn't loaded fully or was loaded partially, this string

```
`$('.'+part+'_audio')[song_number].currentTime = 0;`
```

will return error Uncaught Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11.
So I must reload page a several times - then all 20 songs will load in my cache and playing will occur with no errors. But it is the wrong way. Please, tell me the right. 
Thank you!

You can see my player here (not advertising): http://www.pompeya-for.me

I just start to learn jQuery and create this player for practice - please, don't shock with "indian code".

Comment: `$('.' part '_audio')`?  I assume you mean `$('.'+part+'_audio')`.  Note the `+` signs.

Comment: yes, of course! '+' symbol just disappeared for some reasons..

Answer (score 0):

I've never built an music player before, but I would do it like this:

Start by like you've done but only the first song with all audio formats:

```
<audio class="tr_audio">
    <source src="track1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="ogg/track1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    .....
</audio>
```

The you have the playlist navigation and each link leads to the url of the song. With jQuery you can now change the audio src with the song that was clicked on. You can use "canPlayType" to check which file format to use.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="track2.mp3">Track 2</a></li>
```

jQuery might look like this:

```
$('ul > li > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr('href'),
        filetype = src.split('.').pop(),
        player   = $('audio'),
        newSrc   = $("<source>").attr("src", src); //Need to modify src with help off canPlayType

     player.empty();
     player.append(newSrc);

     player[0].load();
     player[0].play();
});
```

Not tested but you get the idea. You should also add the codecs attribute to our new source.